# NTEXT with more than 4000 characters in SQL Server CE in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce, ntext

NTEXT with more than 4000 characters in SQL Server CE in windows phone

I have a database in my windows phone app with a `ntext` field in one of the tables, I'm trying to write some content to this field, but I get an `InvalidOperationException` with the message:

> String truncation: max=4000, len=4621

I am trying to use `ntext` because I know that `nvarchar` doesn't accept more than 4000 chars.

I've searched for a solution but I couldn't find any.

The only solution I found I cannot use on windows phone, because it uses the `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` with `SqlDbType`.

Here is how the columns is declared:

```
    private string _content;
    [Column(DbType="ntext")]
    public string Content
    {
        get
        {
            return _content;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _content)
            {
                _content = value;
                NotifyChange(o => o.Content);
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm inserting it with:

```
cn.Articles.InsertAllOnSubmit(articlesToSave); 
cn.SubmitChanges();
```

Does anyone know any workaround?

Thanks for the answers in advance!!

Comment: Does CE not support `nvarchar(max)`? If it does that is a far better alternative than `ntext`.

Comment: No, it doesn't support it, at least not in windows phone, It only accepts nvarchar(4000) as the maximum length.

Comment: then I suspect it will truncate ntext at 4000 bytes too.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem I'm having, it truncates the ntext to 4000 bytes.

Comment: Then you might have to break the text up and use two variables.

Comment: Yeah, I started to think about a solution, to have a related table that I could add one or many strings for one article, then, when I had to get the content, I would query all the strings for this article, I will be kind of ugly, but might work.
Other thing I thought about is to use xml serialization to store the data instead of the sqlce, I don't know if it will work or if the performance will be fine, but it's a try.

Comment: nText (on SQL CE) supports 500 million characters.  The problem you are having isn't with CE.

Comment: @Eric.M  hey can you tell me how did you handle this scenario on wp7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your column in the actual database file is not ntext, for whatever reason.

This works fine for me:

```
    using (NorthwindContext ctx = new NorthwindContext(NorthwindContext.ConnectionString))
    {
        ctx.DeleteDatabase();
        ctx.CreateDatabase();
        var category = new Categories();
        category.CategoryName = "Test";
        category.Description = new string('x', 6666);
        ctx.Categories.InsertOnSubmit(category);
        ctx.SubmitChanges();

        var testCat = ctx.Categories.First();
        if (testCat.Description.Length == 6666)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Works on my Windows Phone");                
        }
    }
```

Column declaration:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Description", DbType="NText", UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never)]
        public string Description
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Description;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._Description != value))
                {
                    this.OnDescriptionChanging(value);
                    this.SendPropertyChanging();
                    this._Description = value;
                    this.SendPropertyChanged("Description");
                    this.OnDescriptionChanged();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

ntext supports over 500 million characters, so the problem you have has nothing to do with it.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172424.aspx

You might want to look at the following: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202872(v=vs.92).aspx

The list doesn't mention ntext, but it does mention text.  I'm going to guess that you might need to provide your own custom formatter.

**update**

Look at the following hotfix.  It covers certain situations when using linq, ce and the ntext data type.  Looks like *without* the fix, the formatter is forcing ntext to be a nvarchar(4000)  under the hood.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958478

Comment: When I get home at night, I'll take another look, to see if I did something wrong, that might be the case.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think this hotfix will work with the sqlce embedded in the windows phone sdk.